# Twig and CodeIgniter form rendering issue. Form is being displayed as a String and not the HTML form

Tags: html, codeigniter, twig

My first time to use **Twig** template with **CodeIgniter**. I'm used to the default **form** functionality of the framework, but I was asked to try to render the form using **Twig**. I find the **template engine** to be nice and confusing at the same time. So that means, my controller would be very fat with code. But the main issue here is to render the form using twig.

Below is what I used to do when I want to render a form. View: TableSample.php

```
<?php 
    echo form_open("", array("name"=>"form_reg", "method"=>"post", "id"=>"form_reg"));
    echo form_input("type"=>"text", "name"=>"fname", "value"=>set_value("fname"));
    echo form_input("type"=>"text", "name"=>"lname", "value"=>set_value("lname"));
    echo form_input("type"=>"text", "name"=>"emailaddress", "value"=>set_value("emailaddress"));
    echo form_input("type"=>"submit", "name"=>"submit", "value"=>"Submit");
    echo form_close();
?>
```

Controller: register.php

```
public function register (){
  $this->load->view("TableSample");
  if($this->input->post("submit")) {
    /** retrieve input details, pass them as array to model, then redirect if registration is successful**/
  }
}
```

But since I have to use Twig, things have been a little bit different.

```
public function register () {
   $detail["form_open"] = form_open("", array("name"=>"form_reg", "method"=>"post", "id"=>"form_reg"));
   $detail["form_input_name"] = form_input("type"=>"text", "name"=>"fname");
   $detail["form_input_lname"] = form_input("type"=>"text", "name"=>"lname");
   $detail["form_input_eadd"] = form_input("type"=>"text", "name"=>"email");
   $detail["form_input_submit"] = form_input("type"=>"submit", "name"=>"submit", "value"=>"Submit");
   $detail["form_close"] = form_close();

   //codes for saving here

   //call twig view
   $this->twig->display("tableSample.html.twig", $detail);
}
```

tableSample.html.twig would be like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  {{ form_open }} //will display form as a **String** and not THE **HTML** like this:
    <form method="post" name="form_reg" id="form_reg"></form>
  {{ form_close }} 
</body>
</html>
```

I know I'm missing something, please point me to the right way of rendering this. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

ok, I think I got it. `raw` made it possible. [Twig Raw Filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html)

Comment: 2014 answer, still helps me. Thanks!